# ¿Cómo hago que en una variable cmd se eliminen todos los caracteres hasta cierto carácter?

Tags: cmd, batch

Estoy intentando hacer que se almacene una variable para después hacer un `rename` y cambiar la extensión de un archivo, pero no se como hacerlo

Mi código es :

```
@echo off
set file=%1
rem Aquí obtengo el nombre del archivo
rem Ejemplo "%desktop%\1.exe" (para no escribir todo)
set file2=%file:~1,-5%
rem Aquí eliminamos la extensión del archivo y las comillas
rem Luego una nueva extensión
set ext=.bat
rename %1 "%file2%%ext%"
echo "%file2%%ext%"
```

Aquí yo esperaba que el archivo se renombrara a .bat, pero marcó sintaxis incorrecta

Se tiene que quitar desde %desktop% hasta la última `\` quedando así :

```
set file2

  - file2=ejemplo
```

> dejando sólo el nombre del archivo para renombrarlo

pero no se como hacerlo, ¿alguien ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuación, te paso el código modificado:

```
echo off
rem Aquí obtengo el nombre del archivo (sin extensión)
set fileName=%~n1
rem Luego una nueva extensión
set ext=.bat
rename %1 "%fileName%%ext%"
echo "%fileName%%ext%"
```

Te hago 3 observaciones acerca de las modificaciones:

- Con **%~n1**, obtenés el nombre del archivo, sin extensiones, ni
  ruta. Con la forma anterior, tendrías problemas si la extensión no
  fuera de 3 caracteres.
- La variable para acceder al escritorio es **%userProfile%\desktop**, no **%desktop%**.
- Aún escribiendo correctamente la variable de entorno del punto
  anterior, el comando **rename** que ejecutás dentro del código aún te va a arrojar error, debido a que el segundo parámetro solo debe corresponder al nombre del nuevo archivo, sin incluir la ruta.

Lo correcto sería:

```
rename "c:\directorio\archivo.exe" "archivo.bat"
```

En lugar de:

```
rename "c:\directorio\archivo.exe" "c:\directorio\archivo.bat"
```

Un abrazo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió mucho, pero %desktop% es un ejemplo, no una variaable de entorno real

Comment: Ah, ok, ok. Lo supuse por tu comentario en el código, pero creí oportuno aclararlo por si en realidad lo estabas llamando de esa manera, y por otra parte para no confundir a quien quiera reutilizar tu código. Saludos.

Comment: Bueno, igual---

Comment: Y de hecho, quería obtener el puro nombre sin ruta ni extensiones ya que me acorde del funcionamiento de rename